# How can I target <td> and <th> except for the first and last <tr>?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I target some child elements *except* where the parent is the first or last child to *its* parent?

See the comments in my CSS for a better idea of what I mean.

**CSS:**

```
/* Always apply */
tr th, tr td
{
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* Apply to all except first <tr> */
tr th, tr td
{
    padding-top: 5px;
}

/* Apply to all except last <tr> */
tr th, tr td
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Born</th>
        <td><time datetime="1986-11-05">5<sup>th</sup> November 1986</time></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Sports</th>
        <td>Football<br />Tennis</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Teams</th>
        <td>Liverpool FC<br />Spain FC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why does this question have 3 downvotes? Is it because the meaning of the question was significantly altered through owner edits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you have a solution in the questions you linked. Use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/%3anot) pseudo-class:

```
/* Apply to all except first <tr> */
tr:not(:first-child) th, tr:not(:first-child) td{
    padding-top: 5px;
}

/* Apply to all except last <tr> */
tr:not(:last-child) th, tr:not(:last-child) td{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xSNx)

(this won't work in IE 8 though)

---

Alternative for IE 7+, if the border styles can change:

```
/* Apply to all */
tr th, tr td{
    border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

/* Remove styles from first */
tr:first-child th, tr:first-child td{
    border-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

or

```
/* Apply to all but first */
tr + tr th, tr + tr td{
    border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

(but not sure if `+` is supported by IE 7)

Comment: I'd like to use sibling combinators.

Comment: You can only do that if you know the number of `TRs` in your table. Do you?

Comment: `tr + tr th, tr + tr td{ padding-top: 5px; }` works great! I'll use that for the 'all except first' scenario. As you've pointed out though, doing the reverse is impractical. I'll use `:not` for the 'all except last' scenario. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: You know that you could add `border-top` instead, and then you would only need to remove it from the `first-child` which works in IE 7 ? [Here's is what I'm talking about](http://jsfiddle.net/MM3M5/)

Comment: Accepted! The last block of code is perfect! FYI, `+` is the sibling combinator I was referring to, and **is** compatible with IE7.

Answer (score 1):

```
tr th,
tr td
    {} /* always apply */

tr:first-child th,
tr:first-child td
    {} /* apply only to td and th of the first tr */

tr:last-child th,
tr:last-child td
    {} /* apply only to td and th of the last tr */
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to style all *except* the first and last child. Not *just* the first and last child.

Comment: it is not, first define the basic css, then override using first-child and last-child

Comment: this would work also on older but still used browsers (like ie7 and ie8)

Comment: ie7 and ie8 don't support :not()

Comment: I see what you're getting at now, it was just a little unclear due to containing no styles. Unfortunately, I'm getting an error message when I try to remove my downvote from this answer. Another user from chat has added an upvote to balance out the downvote I can't remove.

Comment: @wes: You could have written that in your answer instead of leaving the OP confused (and receiving that downvote as a result).

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by doing

```
tr:not(:first-child) th, tr:not(:first-child) td{
 padding-top:5px;
}
tr:not(:last-child) th, tr:not(:last-child) td{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

You could also add one class for the first and last of each, perhaps something like `firstth` and `lastth`. This would most certainly be the easiest solution. It is supported by all browsers as well

Also, as wes said, you could define the normal, then apply different styles for the first and last, although this is not as great of a method of completion

```
tr th, tr td{
 padding: 5px 0; /*I would combine the padding for top and bottom for a more condensed and semantically correct markup*/

 border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}
tr:first-child th, tr:first-child td{
 padding:top: 0;
}
tr:last-child th, tr:last-child td{
 border-bottom:0;
 padding-bottom:0
```

Comment: How is this an invalid answer? It accomplishes the goal

Comment: it is a valid answer, like the mine, there is no reason to vote down

Comment: @Danny the answer to your question resides in the link to the question that you posted in the question you asked

Comment: I've removed that link. It doesn't do what I thought. Also, this answer is invalid. I need to target the 'all except first' and 'all except last' separately, not together.

Comment: @Danny then separate them.

Answer (score 1):

```
tr:first-child ~ tr:not(:last-child) td,
tr:first-child ~ tr:not(:last-child) th
    {background:red;}
```

this is the best you can archive with siblings combinators, but it will not work with older browsers, because of :not and probably also ~

Comment: What's this supposed to target? All except first or all except last? What's the other half of the answer?

Comment: I don't want both, I need them separate.

Comment: LOL this is unreal. trust me that you don't even know what do you want. you already had both answers.. leaving here and flagged for moderator attention

Comment: I think it's you that doesn't know what I want. I've stated it very clearly in the original CSS source that I need to target 'all except first' and 'all except last' separately!

Comment: in what kind of world you try to explain what you are trying to do __using some code that doesn't work__ instead of simple english words? this is the first time you ask clearly what you are trying to do and you got the answer from @OneTrickPony

Comment: I suggest you delete your answer and stop getting in a hissyfit over nothing. You've clearly misread the question. Your other answer is much better.

Comment: since you received lot of answers that you didn't like, maybe the problem was how you wrote the question

Comment: You can see from my CSS very clearly what I needed to achieve... Heck, I even wrote "See the comments in my CSS for a better idea of what I mean" specifically for that reason.